# Right and Left Scrolling with Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs: left, midle and right. Middle is for the contents, while the left div and the rightdiv is used only for a button that will scroll the middle div. The content of the middle div is going to be lists of pictures. So, if the user want to see the pictures that is still hidden in the right side of the middle div, they can click the right div to scroll it to the the right.

I hope my question can be understood.

This script is not working for my divs. I think anyone here can give me another script that can control those divs.

Here is only the script that I cannot use

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#left").click(function () { 
       var leftPos = $('.DivDataMain').scrollLeft();
       $(".DivDataMain").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 250}, 600);
  });   

       $("#right").click(function () { 
       var leftPos2 = $('.DivDataMain').scrollLeft();
       $(".DivDataMain").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos2 - 250}, 600);
  });   
       });
```

**FIDDLE:**

[Scroll Left to Right with Button](http://jsfiddle.net/Alkasih/swQ7J/1/)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could use the scrollIntoView jquery plugin.

Then instead of scrolling the middle div. Maintain rows and columns of images.

Say you have a table of images with columns and rows.  Say there are 10 columns.

Calculate the width of said columns to determine what columns are in view.

If the user clicks right button, it simply grabs an image from the 11th column and does scroll into view on it, or vice versa for going left.

And as you scroll an image into view keep track of the left most column index and right most column index.

Comment: Thank for the advice, man. I will give it a try as soon as I find it may be better.

Comment: Actually if you use a table, it might work better to scroll the column the image is in into view.  Then your basing it on the column and not 1 out of x images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your script is accurate. I think the problem you're running into is two-fold:

1. You must have a width set on the container div
2. Your content in the middle div must exceed the current width of the div, otherwise jQuery won't scroll it

[Here's a DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/onejdc/swQ7J/4/)

```
.DivDataMain {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block; 
    background:#000; 
    height:400px; 
    margin:auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: please see my demo...it uses the same divs, essentially.

Comment: Hi, it works, but only for the left, not for the right. what's wrong with the right button?

Comment: nothing. there's just no content that needs to be scrolled. scroll it left first, then scroll it back to the right.  It can't scroll in a direction if there isn't any hidden content to bring into view.

Comment: how to set the slider that limit my content, so the slider will stop to slide the div if from the side that want to slide there is no content anymore to show?

Answer (score 0):

You could just float and fix your right colomn to the right side with absolute layout.

And let the browser scroll right to left natively.  Just margin pad the outer content to the same width as the right column div the same width as the right div.  That way when they scroll all the way to the right the right div isn't hiding the remaining content.

Comment: I want it to be interactive. The content of the middle div is going to be lists of pictures.

Comment: Can you post an example of your divs and the css they are using?

Answer (score 0):

as John says script is fine ... you might consider using slide in whole 's rather than animating the div by 250px ... that limits your choices of picture later ... try this https://github.com/eamonnkillian/Slide-in-Frames

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link, but can I preview its demo with a link that you have to see how it works?

Comment: Quick AWS machine to have a look ... http://ec2-54-186-182-242.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/Slide-in-Frames/

Comment: Based on the John's fiddle demo, how to set the slider that limit my pictures, as how you suggest...